# Directory.CreateDirectory() in Windows 7 desktop application running at Windows 8 doesn't create new directory

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

Several months ago, I wrote a .NET 4.0 application for Windows 7.
Now, I run it on Windows 8 and occur that `Directory.CreateDirectory()` doesn't create new directory and doesn't throw exception.
I spent 2 days solving this problem but I didn't found solution.
I use VS2010 and Windows 7 for build application and Windows 8 for checking proper execution.

My code looks like this:

```
try
{
    string folderName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\New_Folder";
    //this works fine e.g. folderName is assigned 'C:\Users\neUser\New_Folder'
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))//this works fine too
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName); //not creating directory 'New_Folder'
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //do smothing
}
```

Please, could anybody help me solve this problem and explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right permissions to do this? Try to create a folder in the target location manually. Try to run the application as administrator.

Comment: I'm shure, I run application at Windows 8 with administrator permission.